# MySql sum of custom column

Tags: mysql

I have a query in which I create custom column names.
At the end of that **same** table I want a row that will sum all the entries of these custom columns.
For example I have:

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(bl.amount, '---') AS BudgetAmount, 
    IFNULL((bl.amount *1) - ( + bal1.amount ), '---') AS Difference 
FROM...
```

I want a column with the sum of BudgetAmount and DIfference columns.
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to add another row or another column? Or both -- another column which is then summed in an additional row? Please clarify.

Comment: According to the comment left on my answer, what the OP wants is an additional ROW appended to the resultset, NOT (as my answer provided) an additional column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(bl.amount, '---') AS BudgetAmount, 
    IFNULL((bl.amount *1) - ( + bal1.amount ), '---') AS Difference,
    IFNULL(bl.amount, 0) + IFNULL((bl.amount *1) - ( + bal1.amount ), 0) AS NewCol
FROM...
```

Or you could explain more

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do that is to use your original query as an inline view and write a SELECT statement using the inline view as a rowsource.  (In MySQL parlance, the inline view is called a *derived table*):

```
SELECT v.BudgetAmount
     , v.Difference
     , v.BudgetAmount + v.Difference AS Total
  FROM (
         -- original query here
         SELECT ... IFNULL(bl.amount, '---') AS BudgetAmount, 
                IFNULL((bl.amount *1) - ( + bal1.amount ), '---') AS Difference 
           FROM...
       ) v
```

Unlike other relational database systems, MySQL will actually force the inline view to be materialized (i.e. the query in the inline view is executed and the results are stored as a MyISAM table), and that has performance implications.

But it is a way that you can reference the column aliases for use in other expressions.

(The aliases assigned to the columns can't be referenced in SELECT list where they are assigned... they can only be referenced in the HAVING and ORDER BY clauses of the query.)

To get the values for those columns added into another column in a single query, you can't reference the aliases, you have to to repeat the expressions, like this:

```
SELECT expr1          AS BudgetAmount
     , expr2          AS Difference
     , expr1 + expr2  AS Total 
  FROM ...
```

To reference the aliases, they need to come from a row source referenced by the query, such as an inline view:

```
SELECT v.BudgetAmount
     , v.Difference
     , v.foo
     , v.BudgetAmount + v.Difference AS Total
  FROM (  SELECT expr1 AS BudgetAmount
               , expr2 AS Difference
               , foo
            FROM ...
       ) v
```

I'm not sure that's the answer you wanted to hear, but that's the way it is.

---

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood what you were asking. Your question said: "I want a column with the sum of ...". I took that to mean you wanted a query that returned the same number of rows, not that you wanted an additional ROW appended to the result set.

Comment: That will be a problem since the query takes a long time, and I need the original query itself. So, if I understand your answer, I'll have to call the query twice, which will cause a waste of time for the user.

Comment: @user1693710:  No, you don't have to call the query twice. My answer indicates how you can reference the aliases assigned to expressions from within a single query. The outer query can be used to return every column supplied by the the inline view (the original query) and add one extra column.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but it will give me a column with the sum, and I want it to be presented as the last row. I.e. under all DIfference column I want to have its sum, under all BudgetAmount column I want to have its sum etc...

Comment: @user1693710:  I misunderstood. Your question said: "I want a column with the sum of ...". I took that to mean you wanted a query that returned the same number of ROWS.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good candidate for app-side summarizing. However, if you really want to do it in MySQL only, there are essentially three options I think.

1. Write a stored procedure.
2. Do it in a `UNION` as others have suggested, which requires putting basically the same subquery twice in one statement.
3. Try the `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html). I'm assuming you have a unique key included in the `SELECT`, e.g., `someUniqueID`.  You need to group on that ID (so there will be only one row in each group) then use the rollup clause to append the additional row. The ID column will be `NULL` in the rollup row.

The statement will look something like this, depending on your full query and table structure:

```
SELECT someUniqueID, ... , IFNULL(SUM(bl.amount), '---') AS BudgetAmount, 
    IFNULL( SUM( (bl.amount *1) - ( + bal1.amount ) ), '---') AS Difference 
FROM ...
GROUP BY someUniqueID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should do this on the application side. But you can just use `UNION ALL` at the end to stack the "sum of all entries." Just make sure your columns are aligned.

```
SELECT amount, balance
FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount), '---') AS BudgetAmount, 
    IFNULL(SUM(...)) AS Difference
FROM table
```

Comment: The column names are custom. So i can not use BudgetAmount and Difference column names. They do not exist in the table.

Comment: You have to either used a sub-query to get the derived table or show some more code.